# IR LED current not adding up

Tags: led, infrared

I'm trying to power 8 IR LEDs in series with a resistor at 12V. The forward current is 100mA, forward voltage is 1.2V-1.6V.

$$R=\dfrac{12V-8\cdot1.2V}{100mA}=8\Omega$$

So my resistor should be around 8ohms.

When I'm measuring my current, I'm getting around 30mA. When I increased the voltage to around 15V, I was able to get to 100mA. But I need it running at 12V. Why is it so low? How can I get the current to be at least 80mA at 12V?

https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Lite-On%20PDFs/LTE-5208A.pdf

Comment: 1.2V-1.6V in the datasheet doesn't mean the average it means "somewhere". As you're getting 30mA, you're dropping about 0.24V across your resistor so your LEDs average out to 1.47V, which is perfectly acceptable from the spec. The max drop of 1.6V comes out at 12.8V so you were quite lucky really.

Comment: Try lowering the resistance. Since the LED will drop more voltage as the current increases, you would be safe with almost no extra resistance. However, looking at the the graph in the data sheet, it looks like you probably wont be able to get above 60 mA with only 12V supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forward voltage of 1.2V is *typical* when at a forward current of 20mA:
[image]

The forward current determines the forward voltage, especially at higher currents. From the datasheet, you can see the *typical* 1.2V forward voltage at the specified forward current of 20mA. Estimating the behavior of the diode, it looks like above 20mA, internal resistance dominates the forward current. The internal resistance (again, estimating) looks like about 6.6Ω. For a forward current of 100mA, that's maybe a 1.73V forward drop each.

[image]

Putting 8 of these things in series is probably equivalent of 53 Ohms in series... on top of your 8 Ohm resistor. Things will move around as they heat up, but I don't think you're going to get 100mA through 8 in series - you'll probably have to break it in to 2 or more strings in parallel.

A quick sanity check of numbers:
$$ 8\cdot1.73+8\Omega\cdot100mA=14.7V$$